# Adding external jar no main manifest

Tags: android, jar, ftp

I saw two method of adding external jar.

1. First is copying to libs folder and then adding manually in `build.gradle`.

   ```
   compile files('libs/commons-net-3.1.jar')
   ```
2. Other is the graphical method: right click on app folder> import external .jar > then adding dependency........

I choose the first one but this gives me and error:

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java - Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar        /Users/abhimanyuaryan/AndroidStudioProjects/UniSnap/app/libs/commons-net-3.1.jar
>       no main manifest attribute, in /Users/abhimanyuaryan/AndroidStudioProjects/UniSnap/app/libs/commons-net-3.1.jar
>       Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Did you try to clean you project in Android Studio? Go to **Build > Clean Project**.

Comment: Yeah as @PauloAvelar said you should clean your project for the changes to take effect.

Comment: @PauloAvelar after cleaning the project i get this message 

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.0 rc3

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is better solved by not including a local jar at all, but by a remote artifact.

Make sure your `build.gradle` has to following to load from maven central -

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

and add the following to your `dependencies` block --

```
compile 'commons-net:commons-net:3.1'
```

Do a gradle sync after making these changes.

The format is 'group:name:version'.  See the docs on [dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html) for more info.  To find libraries you are interested in, check their install docs for a maven or gradle artifact description, or you can search [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/).

Lastly, want to point out that 3.3, not 3.1, is not the most current version of Apache Commons Net.

Comment: there are two repositories block in  built.gradle file. Which one of two I should keep `mavenCentral()`? 

and should i delete jar file. After including `mavenCentral()` and compile 'commons-net:commons-net:3.1'

Comment: It is probably safe to leave both repos, and yes delete the jar file.